# Best way to create a three channel image with a fixed color?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to create a numpy three channel image with dimensions 10x5 and a fixed color of `[0, 1, 2]`. I'm currently doing it using the following code:

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2])
x = np.array((x,) * 10)
x = np.array((x,) * 5)
```

This works, but is not very elegant. What is the best / most efficient way to achieve the same with less code?

Comment: On what regard do you define `best`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) to get a view into the input `1D` array -

```
np.broadcast_to([0, 1, 2],(5,10,3))
```

If you need a copy that has its own data, simply append `.copy()` -

```
np.broadcast_to([0, 1, 2],(5,10,3)).copy()
```

Or use `np.tile` -

```
np.tile([0,1,2],(5,10,1))
```

The benefit with having a `view` is that there's no extra memory overhead and virtually free. -

```
In [17]: x0 = np.arange(3)

In [18]: %timeit np.broadcast_to(x0,(5,10,len(x0)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.16 µs per loop

In [19]: x0 = np.arange(3000)

In [20]: %timeit np.broadcast_to(x0,(5,10,len(x0)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.08 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use `np.full`:

```
np.full((10, 5, 3), [0, 1, 2])
```

It creates an array of given shape `(10, 5, 3)` and fills it with a constant value `[0, 1, 2]`.

Answer (score 1):

What about slice notation?

```
a = np.empty((10,5,3))
a[:,:,0]=0
a[:,:,1]=1
a[:,:,2]=2
```

Comment: Even simpler: `a[:,:] = [0, 1, 2]`

Comment: I wanted to be explicit, but thanks for this shortcut.